# Cannot install docker version 17.03.2 from Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 server?

Tags: docker

Current version I have is 18.06.0-ce.

I followed the instructions at the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce-1) to install a specific version.

This command is supposed to list all the versions available.

```
apt-cache madison docker-ce
```

But it only displays the 18.~ versions.

```
docker-ce | 18.06.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/edge amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 18.06.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 18.05.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/edge amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/edge amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
```

So unable to do this.

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=<VERSION>
```

How do I install the version I need.

The reason I want this specific version is because [Rancher docs](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/single-node-install/) state they are the only compatible versions.

- 1.12.6
- 1.13.1
- 17.03.2

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using rancheros, and using the ubuntu console container, not the same though. I had the same issue, so here's what I did:

```
sudo apt install libltdl7
wget https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce_17.03.2~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i docker-ce_17.03.2~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb
```